# Regex Patterns for HTML5 Text Field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I would like to create a regex pattern in javascript for a `html text field` that takes an address. So I only want the user to enter `[a-z,A-Z,0-9]` and only these symbols `[,#-.]` I also want to prevent the user from sending an empty string and the maximum number of characters to be less than 100.

This is the html `<input>`:

```
<input type="text" id="addy" maxlength="100"/>
```

I'm new to javascript, so I do not know how to create a function that will enable the regex patterns to be adhered to.

Thanks

EDIT

Following the recommendation by `kolink` I tried this:

```
 <input type="text" style="width:285px" placeholder="Enter A Precise Address" name="address0" id="address"
     pattern="[ a-zA-Z0-9,#.-]+" maxlength="100" title="Standard address notation only"/>
```

This now only works if the other `<select>` have not been selected. Otherwise it does not pick up the `pattern` attribute. However the exact same code works as expected on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/peD3t/7/ but not in the browser. This is the code in pastebin: http://pastebin.com/qQGJ4EK5

Thanks

Comment: Show your part of code for this task and people will help with it

Comment: Try something, post it here, and explain what is not working. This is not a do it for me forum. You'll learn when you've tried and failed and then succeeded

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HTML5 gives you the `pattern` attribute, which allows you to require a certain pattern. In this case, you'd want `pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9,#.-]+"`

It doesn't matter that older browser don't support this, because you should always validate on the server side.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the `pattern` attribute. However I cannot get it to work in my html as in my revised question.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Never mind, apparently the pattern is already anchored. Remove the `^` and `$` from the start and end, and it should work.

Comment: even after removing `^` and `$` it still doesn't rectify it

Comment: Can you update your code to show what you're trying now? A JSFiddle might be helpful.

Comment: I put the whole code in jsfiddle and it works perfectly but when I run the html from the local host it doesn't enforce the `pattern` attribute. I've put my whole html code here: http://pastebin.com/qQGJ4EK5. It seems like it only works if all the other options aren't selected

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready(function () {

```
$('input').keyup(function() {
    var $th = $(this);
    $th.val( $th.val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9,#.-]/g, function(str) { return ''; } ) );
});
```

});

This will work.