# how to get only two letters as alphabets and remaining as numbers in text area field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to javascript and I couldn't find the exact code for my need.

I want a text field with maxlength="5" which should look like ex:AE456, LM975. i.e., the first two letters ahould be alphabets and next three letters should be numbers.

the text area should accept input according to this pattern only. I don't want any alert. Simply it has to accept whatever typed only in this pattern.
Javascript is preferrable. Any help is greatly appreciable. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

HTML5 supports pattern where a field can accept values as per the supplied regex. You can find related post here.
[Regex Patterns for HTML5 Text Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14076214/regex-patterns-for-html5-text-field)

But if you want to support older browser, then you have to attach events like "keypress" to the input field, and handle the event to validate the input

Answer (score 3):

If you have this HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="text1" />
```

Then you could use this Javascript:

```
function validateInput() {
    var val = document.getElementById("text1").value;
    return /[A-Z]{2}\d{3}/i.test(val);
}
```

and call it like:

```
if (validateInput()) {
    // Matches pattern: @@###
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/GgQsz/

This allows uppercase and lowercase alpha characters at the beginning. If you want to only allow uppercase, remove the `i` flag for the Regex.

Comment: Why not `/[a-z]{2}\d{3}/i`

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Oh, I know. I can't help but not use that yet. And there's already an answer with that, so I just wanted to provide an alternate :)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a regular expression. Check out regular expression here. This should give you an idea as to how to check for your condition.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp